# How can I mine Monero on a cloud service?

Tags: cloud-mining

Canonical question on cloud mining: Is there any way by which I can mine Monero on Azure Cloud Services, or Amazon Web Services, or Digital Ocean? How? Does it pay off?

Comment: Can’t help you with Azure Cloud Services or Amazon Web Services but there definitely are several legal Monero cloud mining services. More or less full list of ‘em is available by this link: http://miningtop10.com/monero-cloud-mining/. As you can see, even giants of cloud mining like Genesis offer data plans for Monero. And one last thing, use calculators to check your possible income or define ROI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though there are no instructions on Monero mining on AWS or similar services yet, this might give you a start, back in 2013 Litecoin mining on AWS et al. came into vogue, and there was a tutorial for getting up and going on AWS. All you'd probably have to do is substitute the litecoin mining install for a Monero equivalent, then see how many hashes it spits out, and see whether the price of using the service each day is offset by the amount of monero mined per day, which could be easily calculated on most public mining pools.

https://aloysius.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/is-mining-litecoins-on-aws-ec2-profitable-part-1-cpu-mining/

Hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: Cloud mining is useless. You'll never make any profit.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried mining on AWS, Azure and Google Cloud so trust me when I say you might never break even. I used their 30 days trial to setup mining using minergate cli mining client, which is easy to setup. To setup, use the following command;

```
wget https://minergate.com/download/deb-cli
mv deb-cli minergate-cli-release.deb
chmod u+x minergate-cli-release.deb 
sudo apt install libpcre16 ./minergate-cli-release.deb && sudo apt-get install -f
minergate-cli --user xxxx@yyy.com --xmr 1
```

The last command (`minergate-cli -user xxxx@yyy.com –xmr 1`) starts mining. xxxx@yyy.com is your registered email on minergate.
-xmr is the currency to mine (Monero) while 1 is the number of CPU cores to use, if ommitted it will use all available cores.

It might be better for you to use screen command to run the mining instruction so that it does not stop when your ssh session closes.

**LESSONS LEARNT**

1. Google frown at mining with their 30 days trial cloud server. I am
   not sure if it is allowed with the paid version
2. None of the providers proof profitable. The average Hashpower of
   most of the servers is around 30-40H/s. AWS even drops to 3-5H/s at times. You might never be able to break even.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted detailed instructions on how to mine XMR using cloud hosting, as well as a cost analysis for several different providers.

[Step by Step Instructions](http://www.smith-manley.com/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=27)

I also created a youtube video with a screen recording demonstrating the process.

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt9xFo81Pm4&t=16s)

Comment: Mining on cloud virtual servers is useless however. You will pay far more then you earn.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjours à tous,
Pour ma part je mine sur Azure avec XMRig qui à plutôt un hashage de plus de 400HZ/s.
il suffit juste de créer un Pc virtuel et d'installer le XMRig en mode caché et le tour est joué.
PS: préparer votre fichier Conf.json avent d'uploader L'application, créer un raccourci du fichier exe et faite un coupé coller dans le dossier de Démarrage de windows et n'oublier pas de mettre dans la config (Background sur false) afin que la fenêtre n'apparaissent pas sur les processus de Azure.

Answer (score -1):

I find the MinerGate console miner pretty straightforward to use:

https://minergate.com/downloads/console

You can download the console miner on a linux command line using:

```
URL='https://minergate.com/download/deb-cli'; FILE=`mktemp`; wget "$URL" -qO $FILE && sudo dpkg -i $FILE; rm $FILE
```

Then start mining with:

```
minergate-cli -user YOUR-EMAIL -xmr 2
```

Where YOUR-EMAIL is your login on MinerGate, and 2 is the number of cores.

Note that the default option when mining with MinerGate is to use the MinerGate pool. If you want to mine on a different pool, like [MoneroHash](https://monerohash.com/), use a different host, like `stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333`. (I forget the command exactly, use `help` to see list of available commands.)

MoneroHash also has a good reference for different mining tools you can use:
https://monerohash.com/#getting_started

Comment: This answer does not address the mining on a cloud service question.

Comment: Are you looking for an individual tutorial on how to launch and deploy a Linux instance on AWS, DigitalOcean, and Azure? Because that's outside the scope of this question. This answer assumes you have already deployed a Linux instance, at which point this post answers this question precisely.